# WPF Xaml Designer - Dispose resource at Design Time

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, tcp

I have a WPF window with some resources that create a TCP connection:

```
<HMIDesign:HMIBaseWindow.Resources>
    <DataSource:MyDataSource x:Key="DataCtx1" />
</HMIDesign:HMIBaseWindow.Resources>
```

But when I close the designer window that host the Form, the connection remains open and so,  if I open the form again a new TCP connection will start.

How can I handle the Disconnection in this scenario?

Comment: Perhaps implementing the IDisposable interface in the data source would help?

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I've got same problem. I've tried implementing IDisposable.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do this using the Closing Event on the Window.

```
    private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Resources.Contains["DataCtx1"])
        {
            MyDataSource dataSource = Resources["DataCtx1"] as MyDataSource;

            if (dataSource != null)
            {
                dataSource.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the Closing Event is not fired into the VS designer.

Comment: This should work, if you use this code `DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty);` to see if in design mode then you can not open a connection if the result is true. The types are found in `System.ComponentModel`